# Хочу сделать проверку логина на уникальность с помощью fetch , но он постоянно пишет , что логин занят . Почему?

Tags: javascript, php, fetch

Подскажите , где ошибка в проверке совпадения логина с БД .

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <form action="unique.php" method="post">
    <label >login</label>
    <input name='username' id="input_login" type="text">
    <span id="availability"></span>

    <label>email</label>
    <input name='input_email' id="input_email" type="text">
    <button>Submit</button>
    </form>

<script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js'></script> 
<script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript

```
const input_login = document.querySelector("#input_login");
const availability = document.querySelector("#availability");

input_login.onblur = async () => { 
    let username = input_login.value;

    const response = await fetch("unique.php", {
        method: 'POST',
        body:{user_name:username}
    })
    const data = await response.text();

    availability.innerHTML =  await data;

}
```

PHP

```
<?php

$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "site");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `login` LIKE '%".$_POST["user_name"]."%' ";
$result = $connect->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

  echo 'Данный логин уже занят';
} else {
    echo 'Данный логин еще не занят';
}
```

Comment: Вы НЕ проверяете логин на уникальность. Логин `Вася` не пройдёт эту проверку, потому что в базе есть логин `ВасяПупкин`. Используйте прямое сравнение, а не LIKE.

Comment: А какой логин в инпуте и что у вас в `response.text()`? Не очень знаю синтаксис php-шной интерполяции, но у вас стоит LIKE в запросе, полагаю что он находит "noadminever", если в инпуте был "admin"

Comment: и замените `select *` на какое-нибдуь `select 1`, а логин параметром

Comment: Поставил == , вместо LIKE , все равно пишет также .

Comment: 'Поставил == , вместо LIKE' в sql при сравнении ставят один знак равенства.

Comment: Поставил = , все равно пишет так